# Xcode6 can't archive my project to ipa

Tags: xcode6, archive, ipa

Today I upgrade my Xcode to version 6.0.1, and I want to archive my project as an ipa file.
My process is  Product -> Archive -> Export -> Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.

all are normal until I select my Development team,So I clicked the button"choose":

And then the Accident happened:

```
Process:         Xcode [11022]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 712682811
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [286]
Responsible:     Xcode [11022]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-23 21:51:40.939 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  689CEB1C-6C4F-C95D-8EB2-728905589271

Sleep/Wake UUID: 2F8703C9-8479-4E8A-B4BA-D4B067562EA5

Crashed Thread:  16  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff90624244 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x0000000104aa8184 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff97920e75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff90523dd1 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff90539ad9 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x0000000105f6a535 __85-[IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStepViewController _attemptToResolveProvisioningError:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEKit)
  6  0x0000000104adebac __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff8b85f1bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8  0x00007fff8b85c28d _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9  0x00007fff8b85e082 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10  0x00007fff8b85f177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff973ecef8 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff973effb9 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException
```

My certificate is $99.Every is ok when I used Xcode5 yesterday.Please help me solving this problem.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out !

You have to go into your developer account (https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action) and accept the new terms and conditions

Then Xcode6 stops crashing